# Automatic conversion of numeric objects to their natives

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to make a function that will invoke the constructor of a class given a set of arguments
    package testytest;

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class MainClass {

    public static <T> T newClass(Class<?> inst, Object ... args){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Constructor<?> [] ctor = (inst.getDeclaredConstructors());
        int argIndex = 0;
        ctorLoop: for(Constructor<?> x : ctor){
            argIndex = 0;
            for(Class<?> s : x.getParameterTypes()){
                if(argIndex > args.length || args[argIndex++].getClass() != s){
                    if(argIndex <= args.length)
                    System.out.println("Param doesnt match : " + args[argIndex-1].getClass() + " with " + s);
                    continue ctorLoop;
                }
            }
            try{
                return (T)x.newInstance(args);
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.err.println("Error in instantiating instance of class : " + inst);
                return null;
            }
        }
        System.err.println("No instance of constructor found for class " + inst);
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(newClass(Double.class,5.0));

    }

}
```

which gives me the error

```
Param doesnt match : class java.lang.Double with double
Param doesnt match : class java.lang.Double with class java.lang.String
No instance of constructor found for class class java.lang.Double
```

looking at the line

```
Param doesnt match : class java.lang.Double with double
```

is there a way to natively make this boolean match without case swapping every native type (double,float,long,int,etc?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are constants defined in the wrapper classes that represent the `Class` objects for the primitive types.  For `double`, use [`Double.TYPE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#TYPE).

> The `Class` instance representing the primitive type `double`.

That should match the presumed `double` argument for the constructor you're looking for.

Other examples for other primitives are `Integer.TYPE`, `Float.TYPE`, `Short.TYPE`, `Byte.TYPE`, `Long.TYPE`, `Character.TYPE`, and `Boolean.TYPE`.  There is even `Void.TYPE` for `void`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Both the reference type `java.lang.Double` and the primitive type `double` have corresponding `Class` objects. There is no way to go from one `Class` object to another (boxing/unboxing).

You'll have to keep your own (bi)map.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is with `java.beans.Statement`. It handles all this conversion for you automatically.